# Delete groups using SP Client object model

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services, web

I'm trying to delete groups and Sites from Sharepoint using COM.

```
 Ex: Listitem i = ........;     i.DeleteObject();
```

Now, in my code , I'm using this snippet:

```
   foreach (Group grpsSP in collGroup)
            {

                if (grpsSP.Title.Equals((grup.PK_Site).ToString() + "-1"))
                {

                    grpsSP.
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
```

but on the grpsSP object I don't find any reference to a Delete() method. 
Has anyone any idea about witch classes should I invoke to get the delete method? 
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need [GroupCollection.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.groupcollection.remove) and [Web.DeleteObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.deleteobject)

Here is an example of looping through all groups:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointFoundation.Samples
{
    class GroupCollectionExample
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://sharepoint";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            Web site = clientContext.Web;
            GroupCollection collGroup = site.SiteGroups;
            clientContext.Load(collGroup);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(collGroup.Count);
            foreach (var g in collGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(g.Title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, do you knows what ca I do to identify a group inside So context?  Every group has a name like "group-1, group-2". But I need something like an ID. I'd like to use this code. ButI think I need ID.                           Group testingVisitorsGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetById(7);

Comment: See example added

Comment: mmm. I don't know but it seems tha something is wrong.  When I run the code it gives me the exception : The remote name could not be resolved.

Comment: Did you change the siteUrl? And in your sample you just need `collGroup.Remove(grpsSP);`